# Bean resolved to null inside p:ajax in a datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, glassfish-3

I'm having a strange case of **Target Unreachable identifier 'bean' resolved to null**.

I have a XHTML main web page containing the definition of a datatable like follows:

```
<c:set var="bean" value="#{mainSearchBean}" />

<h:form id="form">

    <p:datatable selectionMode="#{bean.selectionMode}" rendered="#{bean.isTableRendered}" ...>
        #{bean}

        <p:ajax event="onSelect" listener="#{bean.onSelect}" />

        <ui:include src="columns.xhtml">
            <ui:param name="bean" value="#{bean}" />
        </ui:include>

    </p:datatable>

</form>
```

I have a *controller* that produces my **mainSearchBean** as SessionScoped. And as soon as the bean mainSearchBean is called the producer method (@Produces) is called and creates normally my bean. In fact if I go and print the bean in the page, as illustrated above in the code before the p:ajax component, I get the same signature as the bean created in the producer method.

The Target Unreachable error is generated because of the bean in the `<p:ajax>` *listener* attribute.

I'm having the error on Glassfish 3.1 with JSF 2.1.26.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from being a little sloppy with tag case sensitivity you set the variable bean to the string literal "mainSearchBean". You probably want to use an EL expression (#{...})

```
 <c:set var="bean" value="#{mainSearchBean}" />
```

Comment: It actually is an EL expression. I'm editting the answer now. It's a mistake.

Comment: Please provide the code you actually have an issue with. Your xhtml will throw other errors since the tag name p:datatable is invalid. Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes stacktrace and environment. From your provided code the problem is not reproducible.

Comment: True. I'm sorry but I tried to give a simple example because I'm out of office and could have the real bugged code. I'll edit the question asap.